# Wordpress multisite cannot be accessed in local network

Tags: php, networking, wordpress, local-network

i want to ask how to access wordpress multisite in local network.

I`m using *xampp-win32-5.6.14-4-VC11* as the server, and *wordpress v4.3.1*.

I can access **XAMPP** and a normal **wordpress** from another computer in the same network already.

However, after updated to **wordpress** multisite i can no longer access it from another computer in the same network, the address will automatically redirect to localhost and i try to change this line in

```
wp-config.php
```

from:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
```

to:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '[current_ip_address]');
```

it will no longer automatically redirect to "`localhost`" but i still can not access wordpress multisite form another computer.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL , https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite

Comment: Sorry i think that not solve the problem since I`m not try to moving it or change the site URL. I try to access wordpress multisite in my computer from another computer in the same network but this didn't work, however if i try to access a normal wordpress and the XAMPP Homepage it self it will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a way
In my server computer in the local network
Note: the wordpress 'siteurl' and 'home' in the database is 'www.website.com'
I need to set

1. C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

```
    <LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        #Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </LocationMatch>
```

I disable Require local

2. C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
       <VirtualHost *:80>
           <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/website">
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
               AllowOverride All
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
           </Directory>
           DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/website"
           ServerName www.website.com
           ServerAlias www.website.com
           ErrorLog "logs/www.website.com-error.log"
           CustomLog "logs/www.website.com-access.log" common
        </VirtualHost>
```

3. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
    127.0.0.1 www.website.com
```

After that from the computer in the local network who want to access it
*This one fix my problem
1. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
    [computer with wordpress IP address in the local network] www.website.com
```

but in this i need to change the ip address for the server if i want to access the wordpress every time the ip changed and i can't access another web in the server if i don't add another virtualhost, is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/yoursite/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/yoursite/');
```